# How do I add a library made for C# without Visual Studio's IDE?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, qt-creator, openxml

I'm trying to use the Open XML SDK with C++/CLI with MSVC 10 compiler. However, I'm trying to use the QtCreator IDE and I'm still a begginer with C++/CLI.

I'm trying to compile a file of this project, but I get this error:

```
file.h:24: error: C2653: 'DocumentFormat' : is not a class or namespace name
```

The line 24 is like this:

```
gcroot<DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Packaging::WordprocessingDocument^> doc;
```

As the Open XML SDK is made with C#, it doesn't have headers. But how do I make my compiler aware of what I'm trying to do? Looks like there are some options to do this with Visual Studio's IDE, but I want the command line magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [`/FU`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81ex1b0a.aspx) option.  Or add `#using` to your source code.

Comment: and that sounds really bad, but it really is the name of the option

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct, but could you please point me to some reference of how to use the #using directive to load a library (as the Open XML SDK)? Google isn't helping so much. What's the naming convention?

Comment: @haole: You pass the filename of the DLL, such as `#using <Windows.Forms.dll>`.  You might also need a path.